# Updating service reference in silverlight application not working.. Please Help!

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, asmx, ria, wcf-ria-services

I'm building a silverlight LOB application which uses both RIA services and a vanilla .ASMX service..

The data is wired up using entity framework..

I have 1 entity which i recently added a 1 to many relationship to a collection of a new type of object..

Using RIA services i can get to that in my silverlight application fine by saying:

```
instanceOfEntity.NewEntities
```

However in the vanilla service which is using the exact same object context class even after updating, deleting and recreating the service reference in the silverlight application.. the property is still not being exposed..

Someone Plleeaeeeeease tell my how i can get this dang thing to show up via this service!

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up switching to a WCF service instead..

Seems to work fine,

Not sure if this is a limitation in vanilla ASMX services?